# Topologies of level sets of nearby functions

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, differential-topology, morse-theory

Suppose we have two smooth, real valued functions $\Phi$ and $\hat{\Phi}$ on a manifold $M$. Suppose $\Phi$ and $\Phi$ are close under some function space topology like $L^2$ or $L^\infty$. I am intentionally leaving some details ambiguous.

Let $c$ be a regular value of both functions. What conditions will allow me to conclude $\Phi^{-1}(c)$ and $\hat{\Phi}^{-1}(c)$ are diffeomorphic?

For context, I am studying equipotential surfaces of knotted electric charge distributions. At large distances, the electric potential $\Phi$ can be accurately approximated by the so-called "far-field potential" $\hat{\Phi}$. which treats the knotted charge distribution as a single charged particle. The equipotential surfaces of a single charged particle are spheres, and I want to verify that this approximation is so slight, that it does not affect the topology of a low-voltage (close to $0$) equipotential surface for the actual potential $\Phi$. This result is accepted as true within physics, but I am trying to find a mathematical justification. If it helps, we can assume both functions are harmonic.

Comment: If $\Phi$ and $\Phi'$ are homotopic, say $\phi(-,0) = \Phi$ and $\phi(-,1) = \Phi' $, then comparing level sets of $\Phi$ and $\Phi' $ just comes down to comparing level sets of $\phi$, in which case you need $\phi$ to have full rank on $\{c\} \times I$.

Comment: Those topologies won't suffice. You need something like $C^1$.

Comment: Even with a fine topology like $C^1$, or even $C^\infty$, can we find my desired conditions?